# PLSR in R with "pls" package

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

I'm trying to fit PLSR model, but I'm doing something wrong. Below, you can see how I created data frame and its structure.

```
reflektance <- read_excel("data/reflektance.xlsx", na = "NA")
reflektance <- dput(reflektance)
pH <- read_excel("data/rijen2016.xls", na = "NA")
pH <- na.omit(pH)
pH <- dput(pH)

reflektance<-aggregate(reflektance[, 2:753], list(reflektance$Vzorek), mean)
colnames(reflektance)[colnames(reflektance)=='Group.1']<-'Vzorek'
datapH <- merge(pH, reflektance, by="Vzorek")
datasetpH <- data.frame(pH=datapH[,2], ref=I(as.matrix(datapH[, 3:754], 22, 752)))
```

Problem is with using "plsr", because result is this error:

```
ph1<-plsr(pH ~ ref, ncomp = 5, data=datasetpH)
Error in pls::mvr(ref ~ pH, ncomp = 5, data = datasetpH, method = "kernelpls") : 
Invalid number of components, ncomp
```

dput(reflectance):
https://jpst.it/RyyS

Here you can see structure of table datapH:

```
'data.frame':   22 obs. of  754 variables:
 $ Vzorek: chr  "5 - P01" "5 - P02" "5 - P03" "5 - R1 - A1" ...
 $ pH/H2O: num  6.96 6.62 7.02 5.62 5.97 6.12 5.64 5.81 5.61 5.47 ...
 $ 325   : num  0.017 0.0266 0.0191 0.0241 0.016 ...
 $ 326   : num  0.021 0.0263 0.0154 0.0264 0.0179 ...
 $ 327   : num  0.0223 0.0238 0.0147 0.028 0.0198 ...
 ...
```

And here structure of table datasetpH:

```
'data.frame':   22 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ pH : num  6.96 6.62 7.02 5.62 5.97 6.12 5.64 5.81 5.61 5.47 ...
 $ ref: AsIs [1:22, 1:752] 0.016983.... 0.026556.... 0.019059.... 0.024097.... 0.016000.... ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "325" "326" "327" "328" ...
```

Do you have any advice and solution? Thank you

Comment: In the error message you have ref~pH, shouldn't it be the other way around? To me it looks like it takes pH as the predictor variable hence the problem with ncomp because pH is only a single variable.

Comment: Sorry, everywhere is "ref". It was my mistake during writing this post. And I've tried to change it into pH~ref, but still same error.

Comment: I created a fake data set mimicking yours: `datasetpH <- data.frame(pH=rnorm(30,5,1),ref=I(matrix(data=rnorm(300),nrow = 30, ncol = 10)))`. I don't get any error with : `pls::plsr(pH ~ ref, ncomp = 5, data=datasetpH)`

Comment: It also works for me with your fake data, but I don't understand why is problem with my data. Any idea?

Comment: pH is simply a column, try with just `ph=datapH[,2]` instead of `I()`

Comment: I did it, problem is with my matrix 'ref'

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data that reproduces the error?

Comment: str(dataPh):..... data.frame': 22 obs. of  754 variables:
 $ Vzorek: chr  "5 - P01" "5 - P02" "5 - P03" "5 - R1 - A1" ...
 $ pH/H2O: num  6.96 6.62 7.02 5.62 5.97 6.12 5.64 5.81 5.61 5.47 ...
 $ 325   : num  0.017 0.0266 0.0191 0.0241 0.016 ...
 $ 326   : num  0.021 0.0263 0.0154 0.0264 0.0179 ...
 $ 327   : num  0.0223 0.0238 0.0147 0.028 0.0198 ... normal table with these columns

Comment: Use dput() on subset of the different datasets you used to make datasetpH. Edit your post to add them to it.

Comment: I see you edited, but you only show str() not dput() (which would be particularly interesting for reflektance) so I can't try to reproduce the error.

Comment: I put it to the special link, bc it's too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from one of your columns containing only NA's.
The last line of the output of `names(df)`gives:

```
[745] "1068"   "1069"   "1070"   "1071"   "1072"   "1073"   "1074"   "1075"   NA
```

Using your data + some randomly generated values for pH (which isn't in the `reflektance` dataframe, named `df` here):

```
test=data.frame(pH=rnorm(23,5,2), ref=I(as.matrix(df[, 2:752], 22, 751)))
pls::plsr(pH ~ ref, data=test)
```

> Error in matrix(0, ncol = ncomp, nrow = npred) : 
>   invalid 'ncol' value (< 0)

**Note that the indexing is a bit different from yours**. I didn't have the second column in df (the one that contains pH in yours).
If I remove the last column which contains NA's :

```
test=data.frame(pH=rnorm(23,5,2), ref=I(as.matrix(df[, 2:752], 22, 751)))
pls::plsr(pH ~ ref, data=test)
Partial least squares regression , fitted with the kernel algorithm.
Call:
plsr(formula = pH ~ ref, data = test)
```

Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. The problem was really the last column with NAs. Now it works!